# Addition in perl one-liner

Tags: perl, integer-arithmetic

I'm trying to add 1000 to numbers with a perl one liner. Here is what I tried:

```
perl -pi -e "s/ZZZ(\d+)ZZZ/ZZZ\1+1000ZZZ/e" file.txt
```

I was hoping that would add `1000` to numbers between `ZZZ`. But I get the error message:

```
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "ZZZ\"
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "1000ZZZ"
    (Missing operator before ZZZ?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "ZZZ\"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try  to isolate the code with `qw` . E.g. `s/qw(        )/qw(         )/`

Comment: Next you'll get an `Can't do inplace edit without backup.`. But that's another problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use `$1` and build a new string on the RHS using concatenation:

```
perl -pi -e 's/ZZZ(\d+)ZZZ/ZZZ . ($1 + 1000) . ZZZ/e' file.txt
```

Note: This does not work with `perl -Mstrict`

Comment: Thanks! Your my hero!

Comment: When _quoting_ the bareword ZZZs, as in `perl -Mstrict -p -e 's/ZZZ(\d+)ZZZ/"ZZZ" . ($1 + 1000) . "ZZZ"/e'`, then it also works with strictures.